# Texture Painting UV Map Merging

Tags: uv, texture-painting

Blender 3.4. I UV mapped my model. In Texture Paint I select the specific map. It shows correctly? However, each map seems to be combining with the previous selected map. I wind up with all the UV maps combined into one UV map and the painting applies to all at the same time.

Comment: Hello could you please show some screenshots of your whole interface (Shader Editor, 3D scene...)

Comment: Hi, I think I have some kind of link error. Texture naming and link assignment. Let me work a little longer on it, then if all fails, I will send screen shots. Thanks for the quick response. Sorry for the panic. Only the second Blender exercise.  WIlliam

Comment: OK, the tutorial linked multiple uv. I created a material for each. Works. I know linking is good for the same material (multiple uv) but I am not sure I totally understand it yet. Thanks again.